# Using Collections on Java, Apache FileItem sort()

Tags: java, sorting, collections, fileitem

How can I sort a FileItem list?

I have the next code:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
```

This list always can have 2 files (one PDF and one XML, the files name are the same, only the extension change). I need the **items** first come the pdf then the XML, but the default way Windows sort the files are by Name, if this sort change, the **items** can be XML then PDF.

Example:

If the sort of Windows it's by name, the **items** should come's like this:

[image]

```
//The expected sort
items.get(0).getName(); //This should be equals: PAX147896.pdf
items.get(1).getName(); //This should be equals: PAX147896.xml
```

But if I sort for other thing like this:

[image]

```
//The unexpected sort
items.get(0).getName(); // PAX147896.xml
items.get(1).getName(); // PAX147896.pdf
```

Can someone give me an example of **items.sort()** method, I  know I need a **Collection** but I really don't know how to use it....

Any help will be really grateful.

Comment: can you also post the file names and the expected   in them

Comment: sure, I add the how the error is caused, is this helpful?

Comment: I don't understand how the sort type you choose in the windows explorer is relevant. To choose elements in a collection, you use a comparator. If you want the pdf to come before the xml, make sure your comparator orders items according to this criterion.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet I will check it out as you said, Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not a dynamically fix, but it can be done like this:

```
private List<FileItem> orderFileItems(List<FileItem> items){
    FileItem fileXML = null; // index 1
    FileItem filePDF = null; // index 0
    if(items.get(0).getName().endsWith("xml") && items.get(1).getName().endsWith("pdf")){
        fileXML = items.get(0);
        filePDF = items.get(1);
        items.set(0, filePDF);
        items.set(1, fileXML);
    }        
    return items;
}
```

But still don't know how to use a Collection...

Answer (score 2):

Try sorting using the Collections API sort as below:

```
Collections.sort(files, NameFileComparator.NAME_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: Thanks @mhasan, I have this message: no suitable method found for sort(List<FileItem>,Comparator<File>)

Comment: It should be sort(List<FileItem>,Comparator<FileItem>)